# Help with solving an equation

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, programming, polynomials

Could anyone please help me find the real solution(s) to a system of equations, or could anyone please help me find an effective solver to solve it?

The function `Func` is as following:

```
Func = 30*(1 + a + b + c + d + e)*(1 + a + f + g + h + i)*(1 + b + f + j + k +
l)* (1 + c + g + j + m + n)*(1 + d + h + k + m + o)*(1 + e + i + l + n + o) - (3
+ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o)^3 - (-1 + c^2 + d^2
+ e^2 + f^2 - c^2*f^2 - d^2*f^2 - e^2*f^2 + g^2 - d^2*g^2 - e^2*g^2 + 2*c*d*g*h
+ h^2 - c^2*h^2 - e^2*h^2 + 2*c*e*g*i + 2*d*e*h*i + i^2 - c^2*i^2 - d^2*i^2 -
2*f*g*j + 2*d^2*f*g*j + 2*e^2*f*g*j - 2*c*d*f*h*j - 2*c*e*f*i*j + j^2 - d^2*j^2
- e^2*j^2 - h^2*j^2 + e^2*h^2*j^2 - 2*d*e*h*i*j^2 - i^2*j^2 + d^2*i^2*j^2 -
2*c*d*f*g*k - 2*f*h*k + 2*c^2*f*h*k + 2*e^2*f*h*k - 2*d*e*f*i*k + 2*c*d*j*k +
2*g*h*j*k - 2*e^2*g*h*j*k + 2*d*e*g*i*j*k + 2*c*e*h*i*j*k - 2*c*d*i^2*j*k + k^2
- c^2*k^2 - e^2*k^2 - g^2*k^2 + e^2*g^2*k^2 - 2*c*e*g*i*k^2 - i^2*k^2 +
c^2*i^2*k^2 - 2*c*e*f*g*l - 2*d*e*f*h*l - 2*f*i*l + 2*c^2*f*i*l + 2*d^2*f*i*l +
2*c*e*j*l + 2*d*e*g*h*j*l - 2*c*e*h^2*j*l + 2*g*i*j*l - 2*d^2*g*i*j*l +
2*c*d*h*i*j*l + 2*d*e*k*l - 2*d*e*g^2*k*l + 2*c*e*g*h*k*l + 2*c*d*g*i*k*l +
2*h*i*k*l - 2*c^2*h*i*k*l + l^2 - c^2*l^2 - d^2*l^2 - g^2*l^2 + d^2*g^2*l^2 -
2*c*d*g*h*l^2 - h^2*l^2 + c^2*h^2*l^2 - 2*c*d*m + 2*c*d*f^2*m - 2*g*h*m +
2*e^2*g*h*m - 2*d*e*g*i*m - 2*c*e*h*i*m + 2*c*d*i^2*m + 2*f*h*j*m -
2*e^2*f*h*j*m + 2*d*e*f*i*j*m + 2*f*g*k*m - 2*e^2*f*g*k*m + 2*c*e*f*i*k*m -
2*j*k*m + 2*e^2*j*k*m + 2*i^2*j*k*m + 2*d*e*f*g*l*m + 2*c*e*f*h*l*m -
4*c*d*f*i*l*m - 2*d*e*j*l*m - 2*h*i*j*l*m - 2*c*e*k*l*m - 2*g*i*k*l*m +
2*c*d*l^2*m + 2*g*h*l^2*m + m^2 - e^2*m^2 - f^2*m^2 + e^2*f^2*m^2 - i^2*m^2 +
2*f*i*l*m^2 - l^2*m^2 - 2*c*e*n + 2*c*e*f^2*n - 2*d*e*g*h*n + 2*c*e*h^2*n -
2*g*i*n + 2*d^2*g*i*n - 2*c*d*h*i*n + 2*d*e*f*h*j*n + 2*f*i*j*n - 2*d^2*f*i*j*n
+ 2*d*e*f*g*k*n - 4*c*e*f*h*k*n + 2*c*d*f*i*k*n - 2*d*e*j*k*n - 2*h*i*j*k*n +
2*c*e*k^2*n + 2*g*i*k^2*n + 2*f*g*l*n - 2*d^2*f*g*l*n + 2*c*d*f*h*l*n - 2*j*l*n
+ 2*d^2*j*l*n + 2*h^2*j*l*n - 2*c*d*k*l*n - 2*g*h*k*l*n + 2*d*e*m*n -
2*d*e*f^2*m*n + 2*h*i*m*n - 2*f*i*k*m*n - 2*f*h*l*m*n + 2*k*l*m*n + n^2 -
d^2*n^2 - f^2*n^2 + d^2*f^2*n^2 - h^2*n^2 + 2*f*h*k*n^2 - k^2*n^2 - 2*d*e*o +
2*d*e*f^2*o + 2*d*e*g^2*o - 2*c*e*g*h*o - 2*c*d*g*i*o - 2*h*i*o + 2*c^2*h*i*o -
4*d*e*f*g*j*o + 2*c*e*f*h*j*o + 2*c*d*f*i*j*o + 2*d*e*j^2*o + 2*h*i*j^2*o +
2*c*e*f*g*k*o + 2*f*i*k*o - 2*c^2*f*i*k*o - 2*c*e*j*k*o - 2*g*i*j*k*o +
2*c*d*f*g*l*o + 2*f*h*l*o - 2*c^2*f*h*l*o - 2*c*d*j*l*o - 2*g*h*j*l*o - 2*k*l*o
+ 2*c^2*k*l*o + 2*g^2*k*l*o + 2*c*e*m*o - 2*c*e*f^2*m*o + 2*g*i*m*o -
2*f*i*j*m*o - 2*f*g*l*m*o + 2*j*l*m*o + 2*c*d*n*o - 2*c*d*f^2*n*o + 2*g*h*n*o -
2*f*h*j*n*o - 2*f*g*k*n*o + 2*j*k*n*o - 2*m*n*o + 2*f^2*m*n*o + o^2 - c^2*o^2 -
f^2*o^2 + c^2*f^2*o^2 - g^2*o^2 + 2*f*g*j*o^2 - j^2*o^2 + b^2*(1 - i^2 - m^2 +
i^2*m^2 - n^2 + h^2*(-1 + n^2) + 2*m*n*o - o^2 + 2*h*i*((-m)*n + o) + g^2*(-1 +
o^2) + 2*g*(i*(n - m*o) + h*(m - n*o))) + a^2*(1 - l^2 - m^2 + l^2*m^2 - n^2 +
k^2*(-1 + n^2) + 2*m*n*o - o^2 + 2*k*l*((-m)*n + o) + j^2*(-1 + o^2) + 2*j*(l*(n
- m*o) + k*(m - n*o))) + 2* a*((-d)*h - e*i + d*h*j^2 + e*i*j^2 + d*f*k -
d*g*j*k + e*i*k^2 + e*f*l - e*g*j*l - e*h*k*l - d*i*k*l + d*h*l^2 + d*g*m -
d*f*j*m - 2*e*i*j*k*m + e*h*j*l*m + d*i*j*l*m + e*g*k*l*m - d*g*l^2*m + e*i*m^2
- e*f*l*m^2 + e*g*n - e*f*j*n + e*h*j*k*n + d*i*j*k*n - e*g*k^2*n - 2*d*h*j*l*n
+ d*g*k*l*n - e*h*m*n - d*i*m*n + e*f*k*m*n + d*f*l*m*n + d*h*n^2 - d*f*k*n^2 +
e*h*o + d*i*o - e*h*j^2*o - d*i*j^2*o - e*f*k*o + e*g*j*k*o - d*f*l*o +
d*g*j*l*o - e*g*m*o + e*f*j*m*o - d*g*n*o + d*f*j*n*o + c*((-h)*j*k - i*j*l +
h*m + i*k*l*m - h*l^2*m + i*n - i*k^2*n + h*k*l*n + i*j*k*o + h*j*l*o - i*m*o -
h*n*o + g*(-1 + k^2 + l^2 - 2*k*l*o + o^2) + f*(j - k*m - l*n + l*m*o + k*n*o -
j*o^2)) + b*(h*k + i*l - h*j*m - i*l*m^2 - i*j*n + i*k*m*n + h*l*m*n - h*k*n^2 -
i*k*o - h*l*o + i*j*m*o + h*j*n*o + f*(-1 + m^2 + n^2 - 2*m*n*o + o^2) + g*(j -
k*m - l*n + l*m*o + k*n*o - j*o^2))) - 2* b*(e*(h*i*k + l - h^2*l - h*i*j*m -
l*m^2 - j*n + h^2*j*n + k*m*n - k*o + j*m*o + g*(i*j - i*k*m + 2*h*l*m - h*k*n -
h*j*o) + g^2*(-l + k*o) + f*(i*(-1 + m^2) + g*n - h*m*n + h*o - g*m*o)) + d*(k -
i^2*k + h*i*l - j*m + i^2*j*m - h*i*j*n + l*m*n - k*n^2 + g*h*(j - l*n) - l*o +
j*n*o - g*i*(l*m - 2*k*n + j*o) + g^2*(-k + l*o) + f*(g*m - i*m*n + h*(-1 + n^2)
+ i*o - g*n*o)) + c*(g*h*k + g*i*l - k*m + i^2*k*m - h*i*l*m - h*i*k*n - l*n +
h^2*l*n - g*i*k*o - g*h*l*o + l*m*o + k*n*o - j*(-1 + h^2 + i^2 - 2*h*i*o + o^2)
+ f*(h*m + i*n - i*m*o - h*n*o + g*(-1 + o^2)))))*p
```

Then, I try to solve it as follows:

```
Solve[
  Grad[Func, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p}] == 0 && 
  a^2 <= 1 && 1 + 2 a b f >= a^2 + b^2 + f^2, 
  Reals]
```

If the exact solution(s) can't be found, how about the real numerical solution(s)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. Would you please provide Mathematica Code instead of a picture of the function (this is a lot of typing....)

Comment: @mgamer  Thank you for your comment. It is actually not a picture but a word file there.

Comment: That function should be in the actual post since it is not all that large. But the gradient is sufficiently complicated that it might not be feasible for `Solve` to handle in finite time.

Comment: Just FYI, the Func is a polynomial function.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Just wondering, is there a way to know in advance how long would it take for Mathematica 12 to complete its execution of its solver if it can solve an equation? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is for free! ;-)

(Sorry, didn't understand the purpose of your comment "By the way, I paid nearly $2000 for Mathematica.")

Try NMinimize:

```
 NMinimize[{Grad[Func, Variables[Func]].Grad[Func, Variables[Func]],a^2 <= 1 && 1 + 2 a b f >= a^2 + b^2 + f^2}, Variables[Func]]
 (*{4.20993*10^-18, {a -> -0.754063, b -> -0.0172513, c -> 0.763396, 
 d -> -0.647301, e -> -0.490722, f -> -0.122599, g -> -0.686903, 
 h -> 0.0259991, i -> 0.537566, j -> -0.064485, k -> -0.226188, 
 l -> -0.0367157, m -> -0.270598, n -> -0.96309, o -> -0.0470382, 
 p -> -9.82239*10^-9}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering, is there any way to find the exact number (an irrational number probably) for the decimal  -0.754063...? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, no idea...

Comment: Here is another numeric solution a = -0.108371825903906, b = 0.183036421731189, c = -0.321287732364274, d = -0.300042846871963, e = -0.0539627467981417, f = 0.0202299076682745, g = -0.137215427232798, h = -0.236049335717380, i = -0.236071293606814, j = -0.235666224473302, k = -0.234735815328932, l = 0.312652354853718, m = -0.387029122408336, n = -0.385637981205846, o = -0.386981791125416, p = 0.899198837368336.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for your comment. Could you please let me know which solver did you use? Thanks.